# Assign headers to dataframe

Tags: r, date, plot, dataframe, lines

I have created a data.frame of MM/DD and a Value for a an entire year (below is a snapshot of the first 2 weeks)

```
Data


            Data
01/01 0.12698413
01/02 0.17460317
01/03 0.22222222
01/04 0.03174603
01/05 0.19047619
01/06 0.06349206
01/07 0.36507937
01/08 0.12698413
01/09 0.11111111
01/10 0.38095238
01/11 0.07936508
01/12 0.17460317
01/13 0.17460317
01/14 0.07936508 

plot(Data)
```

The data plots a lovely chart with an obvious trend, although I need the chart to be a smoothed line for which I need an x and a y value, which is why I need the data as 2 named columns. At the moment the chart displays 'x1' on the vertical and 'Index' on the horizontal, the x1 values are correct but index needs to display MM/DD and I am not sure how to get R to view the above data as two separate columns so I can then create a nice smoothed line graph.

Comment: Create a new date field from rownames "MM/DD".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I am not sure how to do the above? Could you explain in some more detail?

Comment: Do something like `Data$Day <- rownames(Data)`.

Comment: Okay, so that gives me all my dates without values, do I then need to isolate the values and then combine both sets of data to get my 2 columns that I can then plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a date field we will need YYYY added to `row.names`, try below:

```
#dummy data
d <- read.table(text="Data
01/01 0.12698413
01/02 0.17460317
01/03 0.22222222
01/04 0.03174603
01/05 0.19047619
01/06 0.06349206
01/07 0.36507937
01/08 0.12698413
01/09 0.11111111
01/10 0.38095238
01/11 0.07936508
01/12 0.17460317
01/13 0.17460317
01/14 0.07936508", header=TRUE)

#create date field
d$mydate <- 
  as.Date(paste0(row.names(d),"/2014"),"%M/%d/%Y")

#plot
plot(d$mydate,d$Data)
```

[image]

```
#using ggplot - "a nice smoothed line graph"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=d, aes(mydate,Data)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow the graph looks great! Thanks! You used read.table is there no way to turn the data.frame into object with 2 columns which have a header? I ask as this is a small dataset I will be using much larger ones in the future? So I can just plot [plot(data$date,data$value)] Thank you again

Comment: Try: `read.table("myfile.txt",header=FALSE, skip=1)` this will exclude header and skip first line, then you can add column names manually. This should give you 2 columns when reading in the myfile.txt.

Comment: Got there in the end! Thanks for all your help!